# Debo crear una función que devuelva indices de las veces que se repite una letra dentro de una palabra

Tags: python, string, lista, funciones, bucle-for

Hola debo crear esta función,
"Programar una función llamada buscarTodas(a,b), que encuentre todas las apariciones del string b en el string a, y retorne un string que representa a una lista de índices separada por espacios. Por ejemplo, al ejecutar buscarTodas(’tres tristes tigres’,’t’), debería retornar el string ’0 5 9 13’". Tengo ya una función un poco avanzada pero INCOMPLETA, porque solo logro que devuelva el primer indice de la letra t en la frase (0 en este caso), una ayudita me vendría genial

```
def buscarTodas(a,b):
index = []
lista = list(a)
for i in lista:
    if i == b:
        pos = lista.index()
    if pos not in index:
        index.append(pos)
return index
```

Mi idea era agregar el numero de indice (guardado en la variable pos)  a la lista index mediante un ciclo "for" para así una vez todos los indices agregados en la lista index, pueda imprimir la lista "index" como un string (mediante "str"), cualquier sugerencia, cambio o ayuda es bienvenida

Comment: Parece haber un error de sintaxis en "lista.index()". Falta el parametro a buscar.

Comment: Si el string no comienza con la letra que buscas, "if pos not in index" falla, pues "pos" todavía no ha sido definido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola viendo tu codigo entiendo que quieres contar cuantas veces aparece un caracter en una palabra, no esta tan mal solo que el for esta mal porque el iterador es un string y con un string no podemos acceder a la posicion necesitamos convertirlo a un entero de la siguiente manera:

```
def buscarTodas(a,b):
    lista = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if(a[i]==b):
            lista.append(i)
    if(len(lista)==0):
        return "no existe"
    
    return lista

        
print(buscarTodas("tres tristes tigres","t"))
```

espero haberte ayudado salu2

Comment: Revisa tu respuesta, pues Martin está iterando sobre list(a). A mi también se me escapó ese detalle en una primera lectura. Creo que iterar sobre el string (cómo propones) es más eficiente: evitas generar objetos e invocar a una función.

Comment: Hola, que está mal entonces en mi respuesta?

Comment: No, para nada. El código que ofreces es otra manera de resolverlo, más eficiente. Es sólo que dijistes "el for esta mal porque el iterador es un string", cuando en realidad primero lo convirtio a una lista, justa antes del for.

Comment: a bno, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Hay más de una manera de lograr el resultado. Aqui te propongo una que reutiliza la mayoría de tu código:

```
def buscarTodas(a,b):
    index = []
    start = 0
    end = len(a)
    lista = list(a)
    while True:
        try:
            pos = lista.index(b, start, end)
            index.append(pos)
            start = pos + 1
        except ValueError:
            break

    return index

print(buscarTodas("tres tristes tigres", "t"))
```

La función index busca dentro de una lista. Le puedes pasar el indice donde empezar y donde terminar. Si no encuentra lo que buscas, produce una excepción, que aqui uso para salir del ciclo de búsqueda.

Luego de encontrar un elemento, modifico el valor de comienzo (`start`) para proseguir buscando en el resto de la lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!, por aclarar las dudas!!